# Gracefully shutting down multiple servers

Tags: http, go, tcp

I have an application that runs a basic HTTP server and also accepts connections over TCP.

Basic pseudo code is as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    // create serve HTTP server.
    serveSvr := http.NewServeMux()
    serveSvr.HandleFunc("/", handler())

    // create server error channel
    svrErr := make(chan error)

    // start HTTP server.
    go func() {
        svrErr <- http.ListenAndServe(":8080", serveSvr)
    }()

    // start TCP server
    go func() {
        lnr, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":1111")
        if err != nil {
            svrErr <- err
            return
        }
        defer lnr.Close()

        for {
            conn, err := lnr.Accept()
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("connection error: %v", err)
                continue
            }
            // code to handle each connection
        }
    }()

    select {
    case err := <-svrErr:
        log.Print(err)
    }
}
```

I run both servers in separate goroutines and I need a way to gracefully shut them both down if either of them fail. For example; if the HTTP server errors, how would I go back and shutdown the TCP server/perform any cleanup?

Comment: [`net.Listener`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Listener) has a `Close` method, and the [`http.Server`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server) has `Shutdown` and `Close` methods. Are you asking about the use of these methods? What "cleanup" are you trying to so?

Comment: @JimB I am familiar with the `Close` and `Shutdown` methods, I just need a way to synchronise the two goroutines so I can call said methods when I want to stop the application. R.E cleanup: I am referring to other business logic I may be doing at the same time (writing to a DB, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by keeping a reference to the http server and the tcp listener so that you can later close them.

Create separate error channels so you know which path returned the error, and buffer them so that a send can always complete.

To make sure that whatever cleanup you want to attempt is complete before you exit, you can add a WaitGroup to the server goroutines.

I simple extension of your example might look like:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup

// create  HTTP server.
serveSvr := http.NewServeMux()
serveSvr.HandleFunc("/", handler())
server := &http.Server{Addr: ":8080", Handler: serveSvr}

// create http server error channel
httpErr := make(chan error, 1)

// start HTTP server.
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    httpErr <- server.ListenAndServe()
    // http cleanup
}()

tcpErr := make(chan error, 1)
listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":1111")
if err != nil {
    tcpErr <- err
} else {
    // start TCP server
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        defer listener.Close()
        for {
            conn, err := listener.Accept()
            if err != nil {
                if ne, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && ne.Temporary() {
                    // temp error, wait and continue
                    continue
                }
                tcpErr <- err

                // cleanup TCP
                return
            }

            // code to handle each connection
        }
    }()
}
select {
case err := <-httpErr:
    // handle http error and close tcp listen
    if listener != nil {
        listener.Close()
    }
case err := <-tcpErr:
    // handle tcp error and close http server
    server.Close()
}

// you may also want to receive the error from the server
// you shutdown to log

// wait for any final cleanup to finish
wg.Wait()
```

Comment: Thanks, Jim. I did initially go down this route, but I started to doubt my choice. My only question would be: what do you do with the `err` from the call to `net.Listen()`? Would you also pass it down the `tcpErr` chan?

Comment: @danbondd: you could, it's up to you. Since the http server is started by that point, you may want that error to exit through the same code path. Trying to make this as concise as possible, I didn't add all possible error checks into the code.

Comment: thanks - I'll implement this and accept your answer.